# Why does my iPhone heat when charged and when in use

Tags: iphone

My iPhone gets really hot when charging and sometimes when I use it. I thought it might do this because my iPhone is cracked and I've thought about getting the screen fixed but I'm not sure if that's the reason why it's hot. I have also stopped using, I haven't used it for a few weeks now but it still heats up when I charge it. What can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: All phones heat when charging - have you compared the heat your phone generates with another or considered just taking it in to a shop to have someone that works with hardware make sure yours is safe to use?

Comment: My iPhone will get really hot while I'm on the internet or even texting. It just started doing this I've only had it for about 2 months.

Answer (score 8):

### 1. Bad Connection

In areas with poor or reduced connectivity, iPhone has to expend more time searching for and maintaining network connections. This in turn uses more energy which causes the battery to heat up.

**Possible Solution**

You can try turning `Airplane Mode` on and see if you have the same problem with heating up.  I also have an iPhone and I myself notice that it does not heat up if I am out in the open, but it heats up and drains the battery if I am in the basement of a large concrete building.

### 2. Case?

If you have a case for your iPhone, you should expect that it heats up. The case, while it does protect your phone, also blocks some air from coming out and consequently causes the hot air to be trapped inside the phone. This will cause your iPhone to heat up almost indefinitely.

**Possible Solution**

When you are charging your iPhone, take it out of its case. While this may be inconvenient, it will help.

### 3. CPU Usage

If your phone is heating up, you may have a lot of applications open. Also, if you were playing a lot of games, then you can expect an increase in CPU usage and temperature as well.

All of the listed items below can contribute to an increase in CPU Usage:

- Games
- Data Usage (Facebook, Emails)
- Fetch/Push Data

**Possible Solutions**

1. Do a `Network Connections Reset` (Go to Settings => General => Reset => Reset Network Settings, then reboot (you will lose WiFi passwords)
2. Try disabling the following apps (in Settings => General => Restrictions): Multiplayer Games, Ping, App Store, iTunes Store. Then reboot.

### 4. Defect

If nothing else works, then it is also quite possible that your iPhone is defective and if this continues to occur as you have stated, I would take it to an Apple Store. They may be able to better diagnose the problem.

### Links and Resources

[MacRumours](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1265290)

[Apple Discussion Board](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5006703?start=0&tstart=0)

[Apple Discussion Board](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2798189?start=60&tstart=0)

Answer (score 2):

My iphone gets hot too, take out the case, it may help.

When I take out my case, my iphone isn't that hot. Some cases trap the heat while it is charging, therefore the iphone will get hot.

Answer (score 0):

This **IS** normal and happens to my iPhone all the time. *However* you might want to take it to the apple store to check if there is a problem. If there **IS** a problem on **software** then Apple will replace your iPhine.

Comment: Apple generally won't perform a hardware repair on a software problem. Perhaps you meant to say something different than what you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

Cases and Charging

Charging your iPhone while in certain carrying cases may generate excess heat, which can affect battery capacity. If you notice that your iPhone gets hot when you charge it, take it out of its case first.

Comment: Can you provide some data to show that?

Comment: data ?
http://www.apple.com/tr/batteries/iphone.html
bottom right corner of page.

Comment: and... the [English version](http://www.apple.com/uk/batteries/iphone.html)

Answer (score 0):

My iphone 4 started getting hot and would not hold a charge after I made an update.  I suffered with this for about 2 months until I got in contact with the iphone company and finally talked to the right person to fix both the getting hot and the battery charge problem.  Here is what you do:

1. Go to Settings
2. Go to General
3. Click on Reset Network Settings
4. Exit the app
5. Turn off the iPhone
6. Wait for 5 seconds
7. Turn your iphone back on. YOUR PROBLEMS ARE SOLVED!

Answer (score 0):

try taking it apart and cleaning any dust or dirt off the logic board then put it back together. I did that to mine it worked fine

Answer (score -1):

DO NOT USE Rechargable cases.
if you use your display colors will be suck as my iphone.

do not charge using recharable cases if iphone battery is low (%20-%10).
after 20-30 charge your iphone display color tone will be pink on the middle of the screen area. and I know you wont want this.
best method is

Im warning you -do not use rechargable cases-
first of all chage using cable %70-%80, than you can continue charging using rechargable case without any heat.if you dont do that you will see a pink display area on your screen.after a while. (within 2-3 months)

Answer (score -2):

I have an iPhone 4S and it has a crack on the back on the right hand side, away from the camera.

My phone heats up as well when charging the solution is:

When you are charging the phone put the screen face down on a table and let it charge that way it won't heat up.

Answer (score -4):

charge through ur PC/laptop, wont heat up that much

Answer (score -6):

Too much stuff in one time that's why I had to reset all my things and it works and it's all saved and even though my iphone is cracked when it's charging so it will work I promise

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Different. Posting in the answers section is specifically reserved for posting direct answers to the question being asked. The Stack Exchange Q&A format is different from your typical forum, it's not meant for discussion. For more information please see our [Help section](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help). Consider deleting this as it will likely continue to attract down votes for not being a direct answer to the question or improving it to be a direct answer.